# Convert 2D to 3D with dimension

Tags: c#, .net, 3d, 2d, 2d-3d-conversion

in c# how to convert one 2D image to 3D image with dimension? Like this http://thorrdynamics.com/images/cam_print.jpg in left side to 3D model in right side. 
Its possible? Thx for any help

Comment: I think in your picture. It takes 3d model and renders it as 2D.

Comment: Thats a simple CAD drawing which is 2d to begin with. It looks 3D but it isn't it's just done in isometric mode.

Comment: I closed this because your link is broken, and your question has lost all context. To re-open, just upload the images here. In the future, please try to avoid asking questions that depend on external links to make sense.

Answer (score 4):

In general, no. You can't take a 2D image, "add a dimension," and display a projection of the resulting object. With just an image, you don't have enough information to say what the object actually looks like.  In order to display a projection of a 3D object, you need to know all the vertices that make up the object (the `[x,y,z]` coordinates of a box's corners, for example) and information that says how those vertices are connected to each other (the edges).  With that information, you can create a projection of the object from any angle, although doing so is non-trivial.

Look into [Wireframe models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wire-frame_model) and [3D modeling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_modeling) for more information.

Comment: However, if you have many images from multiple angles, some programs can approximate the actual 3D shape quite well. See [photosynth](http://photosynth.net/)